# JSTL "c:choose" and "c:set" error

Tags: jstl

I have a problem with JSTL view, here the code part with problem :

```
<c:set var="tabligne" value="2"></c:set>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${tabligne == 1 }"></c:when>
        <c:set var="tabligne" value="${tabligne+1 }"></c:set>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="tabligne" value="${tabligne-1 }"></c:set>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The error message is :

```
Illegal child tag in "c:choose" tag: "c:set" tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like this:

```
  <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${tabligne == 1 }">
            <c:set var="tabligne" value="${tabligne+1 }"></c:set>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="tabligne" value="${tabligne-1 }"></c:set>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

In your code, the `c:set` is being detected as `c:choose` child, and that is wrong.

Comment: you write exactly what i do, but I don't understand where should I put the :

<c:set var="tabligne" value="2"></c:set>

To understand what i have to do, the structure of the code seems like this :

<c:set var="tabligne" value="2"></c:set>
<c:foreach>
   <c:choose>
   </c:choose>
</c:foreach>

Comment: That is not exactly what you did, you had `<c:when test="${tabligne == 1 }"></c:when>` and i wrote `<c:set var="tabligne" value="${tabligne+1 }"></c:set>` before closing the `c:when` tag.
I don't know the logic of what you want to achieve, maybe you can explain it or write another question, I only helped you out with a syntax error in JSTL.